# Gson to json coverting getting issue with class

Tags: android

{"f":"RECEIVED","g":"Siva Sankar","n":"342","o":"PREPAID"}

I am getting keys as f,g,n instead of my key set

My code is:`GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY);
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            String gsonStr = gson.toJson(saveOrderDetails(),OrderDetails.class);`

Comment: Can you add your json model class code as well.

Answer (score 0):

After making a lot of work on it.If found the issue in android that in build.gradle file in build release for debug we enabled it as minifyEnabled true. Make sure to change to minifyEnabled to false. Because of minifyEnabled true keys are converting into original keys to some random keys.